# VMWare Horizon Client Not Fully Installing?

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu, vmware

I'm running Kubuntu and tried installing VMware Horizon Client...
However, it doesn't seem to be installing properly.

I used `chmod` and `sudo ./` to execute the bundle and get to the installer, however, upon the installer finishing it - the app doesn't start and is no where to be found...

This is shown in the terminal -

```
Extracting VMware Installer...done.
/tmp/vmis.MVrY7D/install/vmware-installer/vmis/ui/gui.py:870: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_progress_set_percentage: assertion 'percentage >= 0 && percentage <= 1.0' failed
  progress.set_fraction(fraction)
```

Can anyone help me with this? (Note - This also happened whilst trying to install the Horizon Client on a VirtualBox partition: this happened in Mint, Kubuntu 14.04 (I'm using V15) and Ubuntu 14.04).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 14.04 it is in the repository for "Canonical Partners". Check this option on tab "Other Software" in "Software & Updates" and you will find it.

---

It is an installer with an graphical frontend.
If you try to install the .Bundle from Terminal, then you could try something like:

```
cd Downloads
chmod +x VMware-Horizon-Client-4.0.1-3698616.x64.bundle
gksudo ./VMware-Horizon-Client-4.0.1-3698616.x64.bundle
```